# DataGrid Items not being updated on ObservableCollection change

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I've got a DataGrid , where values shown in the columns aren't always being updated correctly.

Here's the definition:

```
<uic:DataGridControlEx Grid.Row="1" 
                               ReadOnly="True" 
                               Name="m_dgErgaenzungsfelder" 
                               NavigationBehavior ="RowOnly"
                               SelectionMode="Extended"
                               AutoCreateColumns="False"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ErgaenzungsfelderEntities}"
                               SelectionChanged="OnDGSelectionChanged" >

    <uic:DataGridControlEx.View>
        <xc:TableView ColumnStretchMode="Last" 
                                  AllowColumnChooser="False" 
                                  VerticalGridLineThickness="0"
                                  UseDefaultHeadersFooters="False"
                                  ShowRowSelectorPane="False">
            <xc:TableView.FixedHeaders>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <xc:ColumnManagerRow/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </xc:TableView.FixedHeaders>
            <xc:TableView.Theme>
                <xc:Office2007SilverTheme />
            </xc:TableView.Theme>
        </xc:TableView>
    </uic:DataGridControlEx.View>

    <uic:DataGridControlEx.Columns>
        <xc:Column Title="{LocText FGG1:ErgaenzungsfelderResources:ErgaenzungsfelderViewColumnName}"
                           FieldName="Name" />
        <xc:Column Title="{LocText FGG1:ErgaenzungsfelderResources:ErgaenzungsfelderViewColumnType}"
                           FieldName="ErgaenzungsfeldType" >
            <xc:Column.CellContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={x:Static converters:ErgaenzungsfeldTypeTotextConverter.Instance}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </xc:Column.CellContentTemplate>
        </xc:Column>
        <xc:Column Title="{LocText FGG1:ErgaenzungsfelderResources:ErgaenzungsfelderViewColumnAuthor}"
                           FieldName="Author" />
        <xc:Column Title="{LocText FGG1:ErgaenzungsfelderResources:ErgaenzungsfelderViewColumnCreationDate}"
                           FieldName="CreationDate" />
    </uic:DataGridControlEx.Columns>

</uic:DataGridControlEx>
```

`DataGridControlEx` exentds the Xceed DataGridControl but doesn't influence binding.

And the code behind with the definition of the `ObservableCollection` the grid binds to, the constructor initializing the collection early and the method updating the items:

```
public ObservableCollection<ErgaenzungsfeldEntity> ErgaenzungsfelderEntities { get; private set; }

public ErgaenzungsfelderView() {
   ErgaenzungsfelderEntities = new ObservableCollection<ErgaenzungsfeldEntity>();
   InitializeComponent();
}

public void ShowErgaenzungsfelder(List<ErgaenzungsfeldEntity> entities) {
   ErgaenzungsfelderEntities.Clear();
   entities.ForEach(e => ErgaenzungsfelderEntities.Add(e));

   //m_dgErgaenzungsfelder.GetBindingExpression(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateSource();
}
```

ErgaenzungsfeldEntity implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and does notify property changes for every change e.g.:

```
public string Name {
   get { return m_name; }
   set {
      m_name = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
   }
}
```

When updating a bound item through the GUI, the changes are being reflected correctly all the time. Through the GUI, items aren't being reloaded using the above mentioned `ShowErgaenzungsfelder`, but the bound item is being passed as a reference.

**Issue:**
Our service layer can notify events requiring to reload the elements. This will call `ShowErgaenzungsfelder`. When doing this, added entities will show up in the grid, removed entities will be removed. BUT, modified entities won't reflect the changes for the fields Name and ErgaenzungsfeldType (which are the only properties which can change).
E.g. changing the column sorting will trigger an update of the grid and display the correct values.

For the `ItemsSource, I've tried changing all these properties without success:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ErgaenzungsfelderEntities, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=OneWay}"
```

With

- UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit and un-commented `m_dgErgaenzungsfelder.GetBindingExpression(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateSource();` in `ShowErgaenzungsfelder`
- UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
- UpdateSourceTrigger=Default

I'd be grateful for any input.

Comment: Does'nt "explicit" keyword tells you to update your datasource yourself? Have you tried without the property `UpdateSourceTrigger`?

Comment: Yes, that was my final try after PropertyChanged didn't trigger the update, but it didn't work for `ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty`(is this the correct one?)

Answer (score 2):

Some psychic debugging here.

The Events raised by the Service Layer are not running on the GUI Thread, and hence the  `ShowErgaenzungsfelder` function is also not on the GUI Thread, nor are the events raised by changing the collection. WPF will receive these events on the non-GUI Thread and then attempt to update the GUI, but fail as it's doing so not on the GUI Thread and throw an error. WPF's behaviour when it generates an exception is to abort the operation and hide the exception, hence you see nothing. (In Visual Studio, you may see these exceptions in the Output panel; there's an option to show them there.)

To test this, you need to despatch the updates to the GUI Thread. You can do this as follows:

```
    public ObservableCollection<ErgaenzungsfeldEntity> ErgaenzungsfelderEntities { get; private set; }

    public ErgaenzungsfelderView() {
       ErgaenzungsfelderEntities = new ObservableCollection<ErgaenzungsfeldEntity>();
       InitializeComponent();

       // This will be called on the GUI thread
       this.guiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

   }

   private readonly SynchronizationContext guiContext;

   public void ShowErgaenzungsfelder(List<ErgaenzungsfeldEntity> entities) {
        this.guiContext.Send(this.ShowErgaenzungsfelderOnGuiThread, entities);
   }   
   private void ShowErgaenzungsfelderOnGuiThread(object state) {
       List<ErgaenzungsfeldEntity> entities = state as List<ErgaenzungsfeldEntity>;
       ErgaenzungsfelderEntities.Clear();
       entities.ForEach(e => ErgaenzungsfelderEntities.Add(e));
   }
```

Comment: Doh, I wanted to mention that, but forgot :/ The events are being dispatched on the UI thread using `CurrentDispatcher`. Could have been a good guess though

Comment: Oh well :) As a belt and braces thing, you could NotifyPropertyChanged("ErgaenzungsfelderEntities") in the ShowErgaenzungsfelderEntities method and see if that helps..

Comment: I've now implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `ErgaenzungsfelderView` and do call `OnPropertyChanged("ErgaenzungsfelderEntities");` at the end of `ShowErgaenzungsfelder`. The ItemsSource is now `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ErgaenzungsfelderEntities, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=OneWay}"`. Unfortunately the behavior is still the same

Comment: Just to simplify, I's change the binding to ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ErgaenzungsfelderEntities, Mode=OneWay}". And if the Grid is ReadOnly (which it looks like) I'd try TwoWay just to see if that helps.

Comment: Yes, the grid is read only. TwoWay binding throws an exception because of the private setter of ErgaenzungsfelderEntities (changing it for testing has no effect). Removing the other properties has the same effect as before.